# Is this is possible to deploy a web browser on cloud

Tags: browser, cloud

I am doing a project in which I have to deploy a web browser in cloud with a editor.
I already had setup a private cloud ,now i want to deploy a editor and a web browser over the cloud.Well i am trying to provide a PAAS for users to develop programs.Is this is possible 
please help..

Comment: "a browser on browser over cloud" - what does it mean ?

Comment: "Nobody understands the cloud" :-)

Comment: @alfasin i just want to develop a platform where i can provide a user with a interface where he can code and meanwhile i'll be providing a web browser where he can search for the things but this browser will be separated from the system browser.

Comment: Did you mean something [like this](http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://www.bbc.com/) ? (check out the URL)

Comment: @alfasin ,No not like this..
Is there are any open source web browser and editor which i can deploy over my private cloud.

Comment: @alfasin please read the comment below i have explained what i am trying to do and please help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not easy. See http://www.browserstack.com for example.

Also there are browsers made to run on the server. See http://phantomjs.org.

Comment: I don't know. Your requirements are not clear anough. What purpose the browser will serve? Why is it better to use your hosted browser over the native? How will it look like. Have you looked at services like codeanywere.com?

Comment: yes i have looked at the services like codeanywhere and cloud9 and many others which provides paas for developers but i am trying to provide a platform where coder can program as well as search for their queries on internet meanwhile i am trying to restrict user in moving data from editor to other system , in broad way it will serve for a software development environment in industries, where a user can code but can't move the data tht i'll be doing by changing clipboard of the systems.
Am i clear to you now..??